# Build OpenJpeg for iPhone with configure and make

Tags: iphone, ios, static-libraries

How do you build Open Jpeg for iPhone? I know it can be done as stated in this thread: [jpeg2000 on ios app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047984/jpeg2000-on-ios-app)

But there are no instructions how to compile this for iPhone. 
What configure arguments do you need to make this for the correct architecture?

I tried this generic iPhone configure file with no luck:
https://github.com/jlongster/configure-iphone

Here is the Open Jpeg project:
http://www.openjpeg.org/index.php?menu=download

Answer (score 1):

I've compiled OpenSSL for iOS a few weeks ago and used the `BSD-generic32` arch for armv7 iOS devices which works without any problems. I've used `./configure BSD-generic32` but I haven't worked with OpenJpeg before.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that the generic iPhone configure script only does configure. That is probably not enough as you need to configure for different architectures, then build all of the architectures and lipo the resulting libraries together.

I did this for libxml2 a while ago, and you can find the script [on my tumblr](http://coin-c.tumblr.com/post/18063869172/thread-safe-xmllib2). Maybe you can be use it as inspiration to make one that works for Open JPEG as well?

Answer (score 1):

I've just published a detailed step-by-step guide on this exact topic:

https://github.com/jonathanellis/ios-jpeg2000#part-1-compile-libopenjp2-for-ios

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do for compiling configure based packages:

```
export ARCH="armv7"
export OSMIN="5.1"
export XCODE_DEVELOPER="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
export PFX="`pwd`/result-$ARCH"
export SYSRT="$XCODE_DEVELOPER/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk"
export PATH="$PFX/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export CFLAGS="-Os -arch $ARCH -isysroot $SYSRT -miphoneos-version-min=${OSMIN} -I$PFX/include -L$PFX/lib"
export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"

mkdir -p "$PFX/bin"
mkdir -p "$PFX/lib"

./configure "--prefix=$PFX" && make install
```

I haven't tested this with *jpeg2000*, but it should get you close. You'll also want to make sure that you have the *Command Line Tools* installed if you're using Xcode 4.3 or higher.