# Using .jp2 images in an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, jpeg2000

I am using images in my app which need to have transparency. They are currently .png files, but converting them to .jp2 (JPEG 2000) reduces the file size considerably. I added them to the Xcode project, but they are not loading when I run the app. Does this mean Xcode/Objective C does not support .jp2 files?

Comment: Actually, though the size on your disk may be bigger, Xcode and iOS have marvelous PNG optimizations built into them which run automagically.  The resulting package is actually smaller and faster than what a JPEG based package would be.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7047984/730701).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [there](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) files supported by apple, and i can't see jp2. So my answer is: **no, jp2 is not supported**.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can find what images are supported by iOS UIImage. .jp2 format isn't on that list. So it's not supported.